# water purifier choices and installation

Tags: faucet, water-purification

I am tasked by my wife with installing a water purifier underneath my kitchen sink, and I came across [this little toy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078XMMDGG) on Amazon, it looks good but the faucet seemed extra to me, 'cause I have one and it's already in place (see the pictures below, it's connected to a heater installed in the under-sink cabinet).

I am wondering, if I can use the existing faucet and its infrastructure such as the pipe, etc, just replace heater with the purifier filter sets. Will it work? It seems a easier job for me than drilling a hole on the counter-top and doing an overhaul.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd run _all_ water at that location through the filter? You'll burn through 'em in a hurry. That could get expensive.

Comment: Not all water. Only the water intended for drinking. Other goes through different faucet.

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't do this, but the question is a bit broad for SE. I'm not clear on what new hole you'd drill in your countertop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, so long as you can make the pipe fit a faucet designed for hot water should work just fine with cold water.